# How to validate if associated Model exists when saving in CakePHP

Tags: validation, cakephp

Suppose I have an 'Order' model associated with the 'Customer' model.

```
class Order {
   var $belongsTo = array('Customer');
}
```

Is there a standard way in CakePHP to validate if the record pointed to by the customer_id field exists?

```
$this->Order->create();
$this->Order->set('customer_id', 1);
$this->Order->set('order_date', date('Y-m-d'));
$this->Order->set('total', 100);
$this->Order->save();
```

Is there a validation rule that can be applied to the customer_id field of the Order model? Or, do I have to define a custom rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create a custom rule to do this in Model validation.

That said, what you want to know is very simple, so you could do it pretty easily.

```
public function checkCustomerExists(){
    return $this->Customer->exists($this->data[$this->alias]['customer_id']);
}
```

Assuming you have your model associations defined correctly, that'll take care of it. Just make a validation entry with 'rule' => 'checkCustomerExists'

Answer (score 0):

i guess there are two solutions:
- first :  make the validations rules in the model like this :

```
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'isUnique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'That username has already been taken',
            'on' => 'create'
        ),
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Please enter a username'
        )
    )
);
```

- second : you can use some ajax plugin to obligate some fields if you get those data directly.for example like this one : http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Hope it helps.